# How to combine a leaflet GeoJSONTileLayer with a MarkerClusterGroup

Tags: dictionary, tiles, leaflet, geojson, markerclusterer

I successfully filled a map with markers loaded using the GeoJSONTileLayer
(https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson).

Now I want to cluster the markers using the MarkerClusterGroup (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).

I tried the following:
created the MarkerClusterGroup, added the GeoJSONTileLayer to the MarkerClusterGroup, added the MarkerClusterGroup to the map.
This did not cluster anything, the markers were shown like before.

Then I added

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    self.markerClusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
}
```

to the geojsonTileLayer which resulted in some cluster markers, but the normal markers were still displayed besides them.

Does anybody have a working example of this or suggestions I could try?

Thanks in advance
Hacim

Comment: I added a java application to play with for this issue:
https://github.com/aabeling/geojsontiles

It contains a simple geojson tiles provider serving marker data for german cities.

Comment: could you submit your solution ?